# Printing out a list for specific elements in a table

Tags: python, list, datatable

I have two list
`x=[1,2,5,4,3]`
`y=[4,8,9,2,18]` and a .csv table that looks like the one below.

| ID | Age | Group | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | Sam |
| 2 | 50 | 1 | Raj |
| 3 | 18 | 9 | John |

My goal is to print a list of `Group` for elements that are in `(x,y) and (Id,Age)`. So for example: Since `(1,4)` is in `(x,y)` and also in `(Id,Age)`, the list would contain `3`. For `(3,18)` would be a similar case as it is in both `(x,y)` and `(Id, Age)`. So then my result would be a list of these numbers, `[3,9]`.

I tired doing `result=df[df['ID'].isin(x), df['Age'].isin(y)]['Group']` but this get me anywhere. I am stuck on what to do next. Any help would appreciated.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: A specific problem with your posted filter is that you treat the ID and Age independently; your request will also pick up (2, 4) and (1, 18).  Your expression incorrectly uses the Boolean values as indices into your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to do seems to be an `AND`, that is done with

```
df[df['ID'].isin(x) & df['Age'].isin(y)]
```

But with that data

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'ID': 1, 'Age': 4, 'Group': 3, 'Name': 'Sam'},
                   {'ID': 2, 'Age': 50, 'Group': 1, 'Name': 'Raj'},
                   {'ID': 3, 'Age': 18, 'Group': 9, 'Name': 'John'},
                   {'ID': 3, 'Age': 19, 'Group': 9, 'Name': 'John'}])
x = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3]
y = [4, 8, 9, 19, 18]
```

It would give also the `(3, 19)` line even is that isn't a pair

```
   ID  Age  Group  Name
0   1    4      3   Sam
2   3   18      9  John
3   3   19      9  John
```

---

You need to look by row, here's some try

```
pairs = list(zip(x, y))
result = df[pd.Series(zip(df['ID'], df['Age'])).isin(pairs)]['Group']
```